Kendo MVC column template with seperate partial view binding
I have this script inside my index.cshtml.
<script id="meterGrid_ActionPanel" type="text/html">
    <div class='btn-group'>
        <a class='btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
            <span class='caret'>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li>
                <a class='open-dynamic-modal-link'
                   data-title='Title #=Id#'
                   data-primary='Submit'>Id </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

And this code then used in kendo grid column template using javascript function.
function getActionPanel(data) {
    return kendo.template($("#grid_ActionPanel").html())(data);
}

Here is the kendo MVC grids basic representation
.Columns(c =>
{  
    c.Template(m => @Html.ActionLink("", "", "", null))
        .Width(75)
        .ClientTemplate("#= getActionPanel(data) #");
})

What I want to do?
Now what I really want do it to move this script #meterGrid_ActionPanel to seperate file as it has lots of content and separating the HTML template from main view file will make the code cleaner and more modular.
What I tried So far?
I tried to load this html through partial view and ajax call, but I think it's not a proper way to have server side call for each column. I have around 28000 columns in each grid so. I have also checked the js and html file options but no luck with that.
Main complexity that I need to handle along with this implementation

the script has parameters that I need to pass from javascript function getMetersActionPanel side, check data parameter which contains around 11-12 properties.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

What are you talking about, a "server side call for each column" ...? All you need to do is replace $("#meterGrid_ActionPanel").html() with the HTML coming from somewhere else. That doesn't mean you need to request that HTML every time - do it once, and store it into a variable ...?

how about the parameters? the way you suggested, I will have to replace parameters manualy I think, but I'm curious if there is any dynamic way of doing this.

If you are talking about data - then no, I don't see why you would need to replace anything manually ...? kendo.template($("#meterGrid_ActionPanel").html())(data) should do the same thing as kendo.template(foobar)(data), assuming foobar contains the same HTML code, as $("#meterGrid_ActionPanel").html()

I wasn't aware of kendo.template(actionColumnTemplate)(data); it works now, thanks @CBroe

I found a way to do this with the helps of @CBRoe. here is what I did.

Moved the html to PartialView, lets call it _PartialView1(). check below html inside it.



<div class='btn-group'>
    <a class='btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
        <span class='caret'>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li>
            <a class='open-link'
               data-title='Title with #=Id#'
               data-primary='Submit'>Id</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




Create action method on controller side which should return partial view. for example return PartialView("_PartialView1"); then On javscript side, load this template using ajax call in one variable.
<script>
    // we will load column action buttons html in this variable first time when page loads
    // and then re-use it every time when kendo grid binds column with template data
    var actionColumnTemplate;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        LoadActionTemplate()

        function LoadActionTemplate() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Contoller/Action")',
                success: function(result) {
                    actionColumnTemplate = result;
                }
            });
        }
    })

    // call this function from grid to load column template
    function getActionPanel(data) {        
        return kendo.template(actionColumnTemplate)(data);
    }

</script>


Called it in mvc view for Kendo grid column template like below.




.Columns(c =>
{  
    c.Template(m => @Html.ActionLink("", "", "", null))
        .Width(75)
        .ClientTemplate("#= getActionPanel(data) #");
})



This way I moved tempalte related html code seperate partial view and made grid related code easy to read and understand. while changes in parial view is also easy compare to inline tempalte.
